# Is there an equivalent of multiple COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ...) statments in Apache Pig?

Tags: sql, hadoop, case, apache-pig

I'm new to Apache Pig and trying to learn. Is there an equivalent of SQL's `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ...)` in Apache Pig?

For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE email_profile AS
SELECT user_id
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN email_code = 'C' THEN message_id ELSE NULL END) AS clickthroughs
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN email_code = 'O' THEN message_id ELSE NULL END) AS opened_messages
, COUNT(DISTINCT message_id) AS total_messages_received
FROM email_campaigns
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

I can't use a `FILTER email_campaigns BY email_code = 'C'`, because that cuts other cases. Is there a way to do this all in one nested `FOREACH` block?

Thanks!

EDIT:

As requested, example data. Fields are `used_id`,`email_code`, and `message_id`.

```
user1@example.com    O     111
user1@example.com    C     111
user2@example.com    O     111
user1@example.com    O     222
user2@example.com    O     333
```

Expected output:

```
user1@example.com    2    1    2
user2@example.com    2    0    2
```

Comment: This should be possible to do in pure pig.  However, we'll need to see a sample of the input.

Comment: @mr2ert I've added the requested information.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that you should include the expected output for the example as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the filtering in a [nested `FOREACH`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#nestedblock) after you [`GROUP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#GROUP) on the `used_id`.  See the comments in my code for more details.

Something like:

```
-- Firstly we group so the FOREACH is applied per used_id
A = GROUP email_campaigns BY used_id ;
B = FOREACH A {
        -- We need these three lines to accomplish the:
        -- DISTINCT CASE WHEN email_code = 'C' THEN message_id ELSE NULL END
        -- First, we get only cases where email_code == 'C'
        click_filt = FILTER email_campaigns BY email_code == 'C' ;
        -- Since we only want unique message_ids, we need to project it out
        click_proj = FOREACH click_filt GENERATE message_id ;
        -- Now we can find all unique message_ids for a given filter
        click_dist = DISTINCT click_proj ;

        opened_filt = FILTER email_campaigns BY email_code == 'O' ;
        opened_proj = FOREACH opened_filt GENERATE message_id ;
        opened_dist = DISTINCT opened_proj ;

        total_proj = FOREACH email_campaigns GENERATE message_id ;
        total_dist = DISTINCT total_proj ;
    GENERATE group AS used_id, COUNT(click_dist) AS clickthroughs,
                               COUNT(opened_dist) AS opened_messages,
                               COUNT(total_dist) AS total_messages_received ;
}
```

The output for `B` should be:

```
(user1@example.com,1,2,2)
(user2@example.com,0,2,2)
```

If you need any additional clarification about what is going on then let me know.

Comment: Really nice--the output for the total in both cases should be 2, though. user1 has two distinct message IDs (111, 222) and user2 has two (111, 333) as well.

Comment: @andrewjd Thanks! Whoops, fixed the typo.

Comment: @andrewjd Double whoops! Should have been more careful with my copy and paste.  Just as a note, you shouldn't ever edit the content of code. Instead just leave a comment E.G. "Hey, did you mess up the names of the variables at...". However, I overrode the invalid edit votes, as the author, since I knew your edit fixed my answer/didn't change the intent.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still relatively new to SO. Thanks for the guidance.